# My sprite doesn't move around the screen anymore

Tags: python, pygame

Originally my sprite would move around towards the gem, and then I made it into a class so I could make multiple of the sprites, and it stopped working. Does anyone know why? Sorry for posting a huge chunk of code, but I don't know which part is breaking it. By the way I'm using Replit with pygame on it. Here's all my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import math
import random
from random import randint

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 200))
surface.fill((120, 185, 136))

head = pygame.image.load("head.png").convert()
head2 = pygame.image.load("head.png").convert()
gem = pygame.image.load("gem.png").convert()

gem_x = 10
gem_y = 10

def generate(head_x, head_y, gem_x, gem_y):
  global upDist
  upDist = math.sqrt((head_x-gem_x)**2 + (head_y-10-gem_y)**2)
  global downDist
  downDist = math.sqrt((head_x-gem_x)**2 + (head_y+10-gem_y)**2)
  global leftDist
  leftDist = math.sqrt((head_x-10-gem_x)**2 + (head_y-gem_y)**2)
  global rightDist
  rightDist = math.sqrt((head_x+10-gem_x)**2 + (head_y-gem_y)**2)

class AI:
  hunger = 50
  rot = 0
  head_x = 64
  head_y = 64
  new_gem_x = randint(0, 400)
  new_gem_y = randint(0, 200)

  upDist = math.sqrt((head_x-gem_x)**2 + (head_y-20-gem_y)**2)
  downDist = math.sqrt((head_x-gem_x)**2 + (head_y+20-gem_y)**2)
  leftDist = math.sqrt((head_x-20-gem_x)**2 + (head_y-gem_y)**2)
  rightDist = math.sqrt((head_x+20-gem_x)**2 + (head_y-gem_y)**2)

  def sentient_up(x, y, self):
    global head
    #if rot == 90 or rot == -270:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, -90)
      #rot = 0
    #elif rot == -90 or rot == 270:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, 90)
      #rot = 0
    #elif rot == 180 or rot == -180:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, 180)
      #rot = 0
    y -= 20
    global head_y
    head_y = y

  def sentient_down(self, x, y):
    global head
    #if rot == 90 or rot == -270:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, 90)
      #rot = 180
    #elif rot == -90 or rot == 270:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, -90)
      #rot = 180
    #elif rot == 0:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, 180)
      #rot = 180
    y += 20
    global head_y
    head_y = y

  def sentient_right(x, y, self):
    global head
    #if rot == 0:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, -90)
      #rot = -90
    #elif rot == 90 or rot == -270:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, -180)
      #rot = -90
    #elif rot == 180 or rot == -180:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, -270)
      #rot = -90
    x += 20
    global head_x
    head_x = x

  def sentient_left(x, y, self):
    global head
    #if rot == 0:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, 90)
      #rot = 90
    #elif rot == -90 or rot == 270:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, -180)
      #rot = 90
    #elif rot == 180 or rot == -180:
      #head = pygame.transform.rotate(head, 270)
      #rot = 90
    x -= 20
    global head_x
    head_x = x

pygame.init()
running = True

aiList = []
aiList = [AI() for x in range(3)]
listLength = len(aiList)

while running:
  for i in range(len(aiList)):
    if i < listLength - 1:
      i += 1
      print(i)
    def draw_head():
      surface.fill((120, 185, 136))
      surface.blit(gem, (gem_x, gem_y))
      surface.blit(head, (aiList[i].head_x, aiList[i].head_y))
      pygame.display.flip()
    draw_head()
    print(aiList[i].hunger)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
          running = False
        if event.key == K_UP:
          aiList[i].head_x += 100
      elif event.type == QUIT:
        running = False
    if aiList[i].upDist < aiList[i].downDist and aiList[i].upDist <   aiList[i].rightDist and aiList[i].upDist < aiList[i].leftDist:
        #aiList[i].sentient_up(aiList[i].head_x, aiList[i].head_y)
        aiList[i].head_y -= 20
    elif aiList[i].downDist < aiList[i].upDist and aiList[i].downDist < aiList[i].leftDist and aiList[i].downDist < aiList[i].rightDist:
      #aiList[i].sentient_down(aiList[i].head_x, aiList[i].head_y)
      aiList[i].head_y += 20
    elif aiList[i].leftDist < aiList[i].rightDist and aiList[i].leftDist < aiList[i].downDist and aiList[i].leftDist < aiList[i].upDist:
      #aiList[i].sentient_left(aiList[i].head_x, aiList[i].head_y)
      aiList[i].head_x -= 20
    elif aiList[i].rightDist < aiList[i].leftDist and aiList[i].rightDist < aiList[i].upDist and aiList[i].rightDist < aiList[i].downDist:
      #aiList[i].sentient_right(aiList[i].head_x, aiList[i].head_y)
      aiList[i].head_x += 20
    #else:
      #sentient_right(rot, head_x, head_y)
      #aiList[i].head_x += randint(-20, 20)
  time.sleep(0.3)
  generate(aiList[i].head_x, aiList[i].head_y, gem_x, gem_y)
  aiList[i].hunger -= 1
  if aiList[1].upDist < 10 or aiList [i].leftDist < 10 or aiList[i].rightDist < 10 or aiList[i].downDist < 10:
    aiList[i].gem_x = aiList[i].new_gem_x
    aiList[i].gem_y = aiList[i].new_gem_y
    aiList[i].new_gem_x = aiList[i].randint(0, 400)
    aiList[i].new_gem_y = aiList[i].randint(0, 200) 
    aiList[i].hunger += 10
  if aiList[i].hunger <= 0:
    running = False
```

Comment: You need to define an `__init__` function in every class.

Comment: I'm new to python and pygame, where would I put the __init__ function in the class? Would it need anything in it or would the function just need to exist?

Comment: `__init__` is not your problem, although there are a lot of issues here.  You use WAY too many globals.  Remember that `self` is ALWAYS the first parameter.  `head_x` and friends should be `self` variables, not globals.  Right now, all three AIs will collide writing globals.  I'll try to fix this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run this, because I don't have your artwork, but this is a lot closer to a working application.  There is still confusion here about `gem_x/gem_y`.  Part of the code thinks it is a global, part thinks it is an attribute of the `AI` object.  I don't know what you intended.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import math
import random
from random import randint

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 200))
surface.fill((120, 185, 136))

head = pygame.image.load("head.png").convert()
head2 = pygame.image.load("head.png").convert()
gem = pygame.image.load("gem.png").convert()

gem_x = 10
gem_y = 10

class AI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hunger = 50
        self.rot = 0
        self.head_x = 64
        self.head_y = 64
        self.new_gem_x = randint(0, 400)
        self.new_gem_y = randint(0, 200)
        self.generate()

    def generate(self):
        self.upDist = math.sqrt((self.head_x-gem_x)**2 + (self.head_y-20-gem_y)**2)
        self.downDist = math.sqrt((self.head_x-gem_x)**2 + (self.head_y+20-gem_y)**2)
        self.leftDist = math.sqrt((self.head_x-20-gem_x)**2 + (self.head_y-gem_y)**2)
        self.rightDist = math.sqrt((self.head_x+20-gem_x)**2 + (self.head_y-gem_y)**2)

    def sentient_up(self, dy):
        self.head_y -= dy

    def sentient_down(self, dy):
        self.head_y += dy

    def sentient_right(self, dx):
        self.head_x += dx

    def sentient_left(self, dx):
        self.head_x -= dx

def draw_head(ai):
        surface.fill((120, 185, 136))
        surface.blit(gem, (gem_x, gem_y))
        surface.blit(head, (ai.head_x, ai.head_y))
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.init()
running = True

aiList = [AI() for x in range(3)]

while running:
    for ai in aiList:
        draw_head(ai)
        print(ai.hunger)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    aiList[i].head_x += 100
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
        if ai.upDist < ai.downDist and ai.upDist < ai.rightDist and ai.upDist < ai.leftDist:
            ai.sentient_up(20)
        elif ai.downDist < ai.upDist and ai.downDist < ai.leftDist and ai.downDist < ai.rightDist:
            ai.sentient_down(20)
        elif ai.leftDist < ai.rightDist and ai.leftDist < ai.downDist and ai.leftDist < ai.upDist:
            ai.sentient_left(20)
        elif ai.rightDist < ai.leftDist and ai.rightDist < ai.upDist and ai.rightDist < ai.downDist:
            ai.sentient_right(20)
        #else:
            #sentient_right(rot, head_x, head_y)
            #ai.head_x += randint(-20, 20)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    ai.generate()
    ai.hunger -= 1
    if ai.upDist < 10 or ai.leftDist < 10 or ai.rightDist < 10 or ai.downDist < 10:
        ai.gem_x = ai.new_gem_x
        ai.gem_y = ai.new_gem_y
        ai.new_gem_x = ai.randint(0, 400)
        ai.new_gem_y = ai.randint(0, 200) 
        ai.hunger += 10
    if ai.hunger <= 0:
        running = False
```

Comment: Yeah I didn't know that you needed the self variable, I restarted it in a new project, just based on the old one, and I fixed it.